# CREATE TABLE AS - how to add column with PK?

Tags: sql, primary-key, h2, create-table

I have to create a table (H2 embedded database) using fields from other tables. I decided to use `CREATE TABLE AS` statement.

My code:
`CREATE TABLE DOC AS`
`SELECT I.ID, I.STATUS, A.REMINDERINFORMATION`
`FROM IE802 I JOIN IE802_ATTRIBUTES A ON A.IE802_ID=I.ID;`

Each row which is generated from the code above additionally must have `DOCID` PrimaryKey. How can I add this column and make it autoincrement and PK at the same time?

Thanks for any tips and other solutions!

Alternatively, how can I make existing I.ID to be PK?

I'm still getting an error: Column "ID" must not be nullable; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE DOC ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID) [90023-147]

Comment: 'ALTER TABLE DOC ALTER COLUMN ID BIGINT NOT NULL' solved my error.

Comment: If you have answered your own question, post the answer and mark it as accepted. However, I do not see how the statement in your comment answers this part of your question: "How can I add this column and make it autoincrement and PK at the same time?"

Comment: This one line of code above only got rid of an error: Column "ID" must not be nullable;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2 supports column definitions in CREATE AS SELECT:

```
CREATE TABLE DOC(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    STATUS INT, 
    REMINDERINFORMATION VARCHAR(255)
) 
AS SELECT I.ID, I.STATUS, A.REMINDERINFORMATION
FROM IE802 I JOIN IE802_ATTRIBUTES A ON A.IE802_ID=I.ID;
```